# Play error: value and is not a member of play.api.libs.json

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

This is the code I am using:

```
(__ \ "fields").read(
  (__ \ "key").readNullable[String] and
  (__ \ "summary").readNullable[String] and
  (__ \ "description").readNullable[String]
  tupled
)
```

The complete error in this case is:

```
value and is not a member of play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[String]]
```

It could also have been one of these in the error

```
play.api.libs.json.OFormat
play.api.libs.json.OWrites
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The solution is to import functional syntax

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Comment: FWIW, Intellij doesn't recognize that the `syntax` package is actually being used and auto-removes it for me. However, everything works as expected with SBT. Thanks EECOLOR!